# Samba cannot share folder - cannot convert name "Everyone" to a SID

Tags: samba, guest-session, smb

After successful samba sharing already few days ago I have the same thing today yet I have received the following error:

```
'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare add: cannot convert name "Everyone" to a SID. 
The connection was refused. Maybe smbd is not running.
```

When trying to start/restart samba service I get the following

```
$ sudo service samba status
 * nmbd is running
 * smbd is not running
$ sudo service samba start
$ sudo service samba restart
$ sudo service samba status
 * nmbd is running
 * smbd is not running
```

My `/var/log/samba/smbd.log`

```
[2014/01/15 16:21:46,  0] smbd/server.c:1072(main)
  smbd version 3.6.18 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
[2014/01/15 16:21:46.426302,  0] smbd/server.c:1128(main)
  standard input is not a socket, assuming -D option
[2014/01/15 16:21:46.428538,  0] auth/auth_util.c:708(get_guest_info3)
  SamInfo3_for_guest: Unable to locate guest account [guest]!
[2014/01/15 16:21:46.428578,  0] smbd/server.c:1251(main)
  ERROR: failed to setup guest info.
```

My `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

```
$ grep -E "^[^#;].*" /etc/samba/smb.conf
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   encrypt passwords = true
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
        usershare allow guests = yes
        username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
        security = user
        guest ok = yes
        ; guest account = nobody
  usershare max shares = 100
  usershare owner only = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with username. I have uncommented this line:

```
guest account = nobody
```

having `nobody` user in my system and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error is also present in normal user sessions. I have it on 2 machines with fresh installs of Ubuntu 14.04.

I have filed a bug report
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1299186

Please mark the bug as "also affecting me" if you experience the same problems as apport will not trigger automatically when this bug occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In order for usershare to work, smbd must also bind to the localhost, i.e.

> interfaces = 192.168.0.100/8 eno1 127.0.0.1/8 lo