# Samba: File location where share entries are stored?

Tags: files, samba, location

Does anyone know the file in which the entries for the samba shares are stored?
For instance the drives or folders I am sharing.

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/198501/list-of-all-shared-folders ? You probably want simply to run `smbstatus --shares`

Comment: No, I'm actually looking to edit the entries with nano instead of commands. My samba is broken when adding a share with an error: 

'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare add: cannot convert name "Everyone" to a SID. Access denied.

.. I have existing shares that work.. and I want to basically add new shares similar to how they're already added. Like editing a simple file

Comment: Sounds more like a configuration error, and I doubt manually editing files would be a safe path to resolution (edit - upon checking, I stand corrected). I don't suppose you've already tried checking against that error itself? https://askubuntu.com/questions/405926/samba-cannot-share-folder-cannot-convert-name-everyone-to-a-sid

Comment: At this point you will need to flesh out your question. What's broken, when did it break, how did you set up the shares in the first place, what version of Ubuntu, etc.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsb_release -a` the content of `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and the output of `ll /var/lib/samba/usershares/..`  as at this point it's unclear what you are asking. Please also review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask for future reference. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: The ones someone else share will be mounted with [`gio mount smb://`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1392839/349837) and will be and will be on `/run/user/$(id -u)/gvfs/`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If not defined in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` try folder `/var/lib/samba/usershares/` and you will find files for each share you setup via GUI. (Ubuntu 17.10)

Answer (score 1):

If you insist, you can edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf` I recommend that you make a backup copy or use `gedit` which will make one (and only one) for you.

Further information regarding this file can be found [here.](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html)

Comment: smb.conf doesn't store the locations of my current shares.

Comment: But seriously.. where is the information for a shared location stored? smb.conf doesn't list my shares.

Comment: I'm quite certain we can help you provided you respond to the requests to [edit] your post with the information requested. For instance [this request](http://askubuntu.com/questions/900580/samba-file-location-where-share-entries-are-stored#comment1413820_900580)

Answer (score 0):

Try in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide

Comment: smb.conf doesn't store the locations of my current shares.