# How to connect SMB file system in command line and how to access it? (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, mount, samba

On Ubuntu, I can connect to a directory connected by samba by opening File Manager and pressing <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> and typing in location like `smb://129.254.32.xxx/Private` then the File Manager asks me to type in login information. The connected directory is seen at `/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=129.254.32.xxx,share=private` and of course I can access the lower directory from there. For example, `/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=129.254.32.xxx,share=private/prj/abdsn`.

How can I connect the samba directory using command line (instead of using <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> in File Manger)? I tried `smbclient smb://129.254.32.xxx/share -U user1%passwd1` but couldn't find where it is attached. Command example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replicate this:

> Ctrl+L and typing in location like smb://129.254.32.xxx/Private

With this:

```
gio mount smb://129.254.32.xxx/Private
```

Comment: And then will be on `cd /run/user/$(id -u)/gvfs/`...